# TInyMCE object Tag stripped

Tags: tinymce, oop

I need to add the following object tag to a page

```
<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
 <param name="width" value="648" />
 <param name="height" value="630" />
 <param name="playerID" value="801136430001" />
 <param name="playerKey" value="**********" /><param name="isVid" value="true"/>
 <param name="isUI" value="true" /><param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
</object>
```

However Wordpress is stripping the object tag and everything inside and replacing it with non-breaking spaces.

The editor I'm using in TinyMCE Advanced on WP .3.2.1, I tried installed TinyMCE config and adding the following to the extended_valid_elements

```
object[class|id|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value]
```

But it's had no effect, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but this problem seems related to the [`unfiltered_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) capability restriction.

> unfiltered_html
>
> - Since 2.0
> - Allows user to post HTML markup or even
>     JavaScript code in pages, posts, and comments.
> - Note: Enabling this
>     option for untrusted users may result in their posting malicious or
>     poorly formatted code.

An easy fix (and probably a solution even if the issue in not of capabilities) is to make a shortcode to handle the object insertion.

This example is for inserting a SoundCloud iframe, but easily adaptable to the object tag.

```
add_shortcode('soundcloud', 'soundcloud_shortcode_maker');

function soundcloud_shortcode_maker($atts, $content = null) {
    $output = '<iframe width="'.$atts['width'].'" height="'.$atts['height'].'" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url='.urlencode($atts['url']).'&amp;'.myUrlEncode($atts['params']).'"></iframe>';   
    return $output;
}

function myUrlEncode($string) {
    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
}
```

The function `myUrlEncode` is just a helper in this specific SoundCloud case, but I'll leave it here just in case...